# currentCell to remain the same if validation fail. - CellEndEdit Event

Tags: vb.net, validation, datagridview

I have a datagridview for user's input.

For example, the columns are "Name", "Date of Birth"...

For the "Date of Birth" part, i have implemented validaion...

i want to make it that user have to enter a valid "Date of birth" before they are allowed to leave the Cell. Meaning once them entered the Cell, they have to provide a valid "Date of birth" then they can move on.

would like to find out how this can be done, i have tried setting the DGV.currentCell to the intended cell inside "CellEndEdit" event. But it gives me the following error: "operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the setcurrentcelladdresscore function"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve this by using **CellValidating**

```
void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 3)
    {
       e.FormattedValue // Check your date validation against this value
       e.Cancel = true; // set this to true if validation fails
    }
}
```

This will help in retaining the focus in the same cell in case of an incorrect entry by the user.